# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation

Tags: java, flutter, java-home

When I was running "flutter doctor --android-licenses", I struggled to fix the error below,

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

I thought I should post this as a question and provide a response to it, as other Answers to the this question could not help me.

Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. run the below command to choose the java version that you want to use.

   sudo update-alternatives --config java

   You will get something like this from the terminal.
   [image]
2. Press the number corresponding to the version of java that you want to use.
   Example,
   Press "Enter"  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
3. Copy the PATH corresponding to the java version that you chose. In my case since I
   chose version in Number 0,
   My PATH is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.
   But leave out the last part of the PATH,i.e "/bin/java".
   So now your PATH is  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
4. run the following command, where PATH value is the value copied from above.
   export JAVA_HOME=PATH
   In my case, I will run
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
5. run this command, copy it as it is. Don't change anything.
   echo $JAVA_HOME
6. follow by this command, copy it as it is. Don't change anything.
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
7. run this command,
   echo $PATH

   This will give out the full path to your $JAVA_HOME value.

   In my case, this is what I got.
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   :/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
   :/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
8. Now you are sorted.
9. "flutter doctor --android-licenses", ran successfully.

Comment: Very clear and concise. Thanks.

Comment: Grateful I could help @adravel